# Windows Form not resizable when on LEFT secondary monitor

Tags: .net, winforms, window-resize

I'm having the weirdest problem here with a Windows App written in c#.

Although there is absolutely nothing special about it, the main window works perfectly well on the Primary monitor and on any Secondary monitor when the latter is configured to stand on the right of the Primary monitor. However, when I reconfigure the secondary screen to be placed on the **left** side of my Primary monitor, I (and others) no longer can change the size of the form. The mouse-pointer does NOT change into the 'NW-SE-arrows', nor does clicking & dragging the edge react in any change towards the size of the window.

Doing some extra experimenting this seems to surface only when I have the AutoSizeMode of the form set to GrowAndShrink !?

Is this some kind of bug or am I misinterpreting the property ?

To reproduce this problem you should

- start a new WinForms project
- Add a StatusStrip to the bottom of the form
- Run the project (Debug/Any CPU in my case)
- Drag the form to the secondary monitor that stands LEFT of your primary monitor

PS: it seems that when I remove the StatusStrip, I can't resize the form at all, so I'm guessing this is some side-effect/bug in the StatusStrip object...

Adding a checkbox with the following code behind makes it pretty clear that the issue revolves around the AutoSizeMode property

```
private void chkAutoGrowAndShrink_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     this.AutoSizeMode = chkAutoGrowAndShrink.Checked ? 
             AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink : 
             System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly; 
}
```

---

UPDATE:

As I've recently switched machines I've now redone the test on this new laptop using VS2010 and hold & behold, the issue is no longer. I'm still not sure where this came from, maybe it got fixed in .NET over time, maybe it was a driver issue... I guess we'll never now but it seems there is little use to keep this question here so I'll just mark it for closing. **Thanks** to all who put some of their precious time in it though!

Comment: Are you performing any calculations on size/position of the form or contained controls? A screen to the left of the primary will have negative coordinates, and it is easy to assume they are always non-negative in calculations.

Comment: Not in my original code, nor in the 'reproduction example'. But I agree that it's probably something along those lines inside the "native" objects that's causing this. I'm hoping others are able to reproduce it too, or actually not, which both would be interesting before sending in a bug-report towards MS...

Comment: I am experiencing this behavior too on Win7x64 with NVIDIA Quadro NVS 140M video adapter. - on primary monitor, window is resizable regardless of whether it is the left or right display.
- on secondary monitor, window is resizable when it is to the right of the primary monitor, but not when it is left of the primary monitor.

Comment: If you can re-create this with only standard controls, and without code to manipulate size/position then I would suggest opening a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: The issue still existed in .NET Framework and 4.x and even in .NET Core 3.x (only when you show the form with `ShowDialog`). I merged a fix recently in the [winforms repo](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/1504), it will be released in .NET 5.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg: nice, tyvm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this issue was hardware/driver/specific version of .NET/??? related. Closing question as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't resize with the StatusStrip not on the form, then there is another issue going on here.  All forms should be resizable unless you set the [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx) property to a Fixed style.

Comment: FormBordeStyle is set to SizeAble. Frankly, I haven't touched any properties except for name, text and AutoSizeMode.

Comment: Adding a checkbox with the following code behind makes it pretty clear that the issue revolves around the AutoSizeMode property

private void chkAutoGrowAndShrink_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

 this.AutoSizeMode = chkAutoGrowAndShrink.Checked ? AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink : System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly;

}  // sorry about missing layout, seems the comment-box eats most of it...

Comment: Hmmm...  Very confusing then.